# I have installed the pgaudit extension without errors, but it's still not logging

Tags: postgresql

1. I copied the pgaudit dll, sql and control files in the correct folders in PostgreSQL.
2. I updated the postgresql.conf file with ==> shared_preload_libraries=pgaudit.
3. I restarted the PostgreSQL server.
4. I connected to my database and initiated the following commands successfully:
   `create extension pgaudit;`
   `alter database my_db set pgaudit.log = 'all, -misc';`
   `alter database my_db set pgaudit.log_level = novice;`
5. I can see the pgaudit extension listed in the admin tool (pgAdmin III), as well ad the pgaudit event triggers, for database my_db.
6. However, only the standard logging is visible in the pg_log files. The "pgaudit" csv logging is not visible.
7. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.10 with pgaudit 1.0.6.

Comment: I suppose you've found your solution at this point, but log_level in your example has a typo. It should be `notice`. The full list of options for this settings is here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-SEVERITY-LEVELS